# call variables from a struct generated in matlab

Tags: matlab, function, oop, structure

I'm trying to find all possible solutions for my problem. Starting from Case A to Case E, I generated all solutions and generated a struct from them.

```
Solutions=    []    []    []    []    [21x10 struct]
```

That means

```
CASE A 0 solution,
CASE B 0 solution,
CASE C 0 solution,
CASE D 0 solution,
CASE E 21 solution.
```

I want to call all these 21 solutions (which are 1x10 matrix) to use my next calculations. For example;

```
CASE E= SOL1, SOL2, ...... SOL21
```

And I want to use SOL10 and I do some calculations with it

How can I call all these 21 solutions to use it for another calculation?

Comment: Could you please post your code that can be used to reproduce your problem? How have you tried to call the solutions up until now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose we have:

```
for ii=1:21
  SolE(ii).solution=rand(1,10);
end
Solutions={[],[],[],[],[SolE]};
clearvars -except Solutions
```

`Solutions` is **cell array** where each element represents given CASE.
Each CASE (`Solutions{ii}`) is **struct array** where each element contain SOLUTION.
Each SOLUTION is **struct** with one element - 1x10 array.

If you want to access all solutions you can do it via

```
{Solutions{case_ID}(:).solution}'
```

If you want to access one solution:

```
Solutions{case_ID}(sol_ID).solution
```